# Field Validation For An IP Address

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, controls, keyboard

I am trying to prevent a user from entering anything into a particular textbox aside from a number or a period in C#. The textbox is supposed to contain an IP address. I have it working such that non-numeric entries are prevented, however I can't seem to get it to allow a period to be entered. How might I accomplish this?

```
    private void TargetIP_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the flag to false.
        nonNumberEntered = false;

        // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the top of the keyboard.
        if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
        {
            // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the keypad.
            if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9)
            {
                // Determine whether the keystroke is a backspace.
                if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
                {
                    nonNumberEntered = true;
                    errorProvider1.SetError(TargetIP, FieldValidationNumbersOnly);
                    // A non-numerical keystroke was pressed.
                    // Set the flag to true and evaluate in KeyPress event.
                }
            }
        }

        //If shift key was pressed, it's not a number.
        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
        {
            nonNumberEntered = true;
        }
    }


    private void TargetIP_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check for the flag being set in the KeyDown event.
        if (nonNumberEntered == true)
        {
            // Stop the character from being entered into the control since it is non-numerical.
            e.Handled = true;
        } 

        else
        {
            errorProvider1.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are aware that IP address can take many forms other than what you're trying to let the user enter, right?  If not, try reading this article (it's about perl, but pretty language-neutral and definitely applicable): http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=221512

Comment: the field validation for this IP address format need not be perfect, just so long as it can only accept numbers and decimal points while denying all other types of input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(loband).aspx) control instead of a normal `TextBox` control. Then just set the [`Mask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) property to `990\.990\.990\.990` and you are done.

- 9 optional digit or space
- 0 required digit
- \. escaped dot

**UPDATE**

While I suggested using `MaskedTextBox`, I never (at leat I cannot remeber) used it myself. Now I just tried it ... well, forget what I said. I thought it might be a simple solution, but it is an unusable solution, too.

New, more complex, but far better suggestion and the way I usually do it.

- Create a custom control with four text boxes, three labels with a dot each between them.
- Analyse the input.

  - Just pass control keys to the control.
  - Move the focus if the user enters a dot, a tab (will be handled by the control), a space, may be a fourth digit.
  - Discard everything that is not a digit.
  - Discard the digit if the number falls out of the range from 0 to 255.
  - Change the text to 0 if the user deletes the last digit.
  - Remove a leading zero if the user enters a non-zero digit.
- Add a property to the user control that returns the entered address.
- May be make the proeprty writable and add event handling.

Comment: Wow, thanks...now the way I was doing it seems silly. Are there any advantages to doing it the way I was with a regular textbox rather than what you recommended?

Comment: how about IPv6 addresses? I think that will get a bit more tricky.

Comment: Yes! The MaskedTextBox is usability horror. I should have tried before suggesting that. It works, but ... it works. If you will have many IP address inputs, I really suggest taking the time to build a smart custom control.

Comment: well, it could be a dynamic swapping of the mask. If it fails on the IPv4 mask, switch to the IPv6 mask? just make sure you don't ping-pong between the masks, and that might work.

Comment: Just as a small FYI, when you go to Network Connections, properties on a connection, properties on TCP/IP, the validation for everything but "Subnet mask" (e.g. "IP address" or "Default Gateway") is: (between 1 and 223).(between 0 and 255).(between 0 and 255).(between 0 and 255)